# Raspberry Pi Qt toolchain on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, cross-compilation, qt, toolchain

I have issues creating a tool-chain for cross compiling Raspberry Pi 3 Qt applications through Ubuntu. I used directions from this guide, https://wiki.qt.io/Raspberry_Pi_Beginners_Guide, to help me create the tool-chain. Currently, I am stuck on this step in the section ***Compiling qtbase*** in the guide:

```
./configure -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/opt/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -hostprefix /usr/local/qt5pi
```

This is the error I received in the terminal:

```
sudo ./configure -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/opt/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -hostprefix /usr/local/qt5pi
<srcbase> = /home/ubuntu16/opt/qt5/qtbase 
<bldbase> = /home/ubuntu16/opt/qt5/qtbase 
<outbase> = /home/ubuntu16/opt/qt5/qtbase 
Creating qmake...
.Done.
Project ERROR: Cannot run target compiler '/home/ubuntu16/opt/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++'. Output:
===================
/home/ubuntu16/opt/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
```

I am new yo Qt and have a beginner's understanding of Ubuntu. I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit within VirtualBox.

Does anybody know how to setup the environment? Should I have the Raspberry Pi 3 connected to my PC via SSH?
How do I setup 'the environment' as mentioned above in the terminal?

I also checked the file location for the tool-chain that was downloaded and everything is there.  No files or directories are missing from what I've seen.

Any help is appreciated.